# How does Google maintains citation records? And how can one extract the BibTex for a paper?

Tags: bibtex

Concretely, if you search for this [paper](http://www.eecs.umich.edu/techreports/systems/cspl/cspl-391.pdf) on google, it will tell you it has 22 citations. How does google knows about the citations? And more importantly, how can I extract at the BibTex for this paper, since of course google is doing it too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is off-topic for our site since it is related to Google Scholar exclusively. So I proposed closing as such. But let's close it by providing at least the TeX connection. If you go to your Scholar account settings you'll see the following page;

[image]

There you can select BibTeX, Endnote, RefMan and RefWorks. But based on my personal experience it doesn't work that well. You can go to the journal site and import the citations directly. Amazingly some require membership to import the citation which is essentially to their benefit if someone cites them. Corporate Stupidity at its best.

How Google mines these information is beyond this answer textbox here. You can ask it on other SE sites.